# Remove extra space from a Bootstrap 4 Card

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm using the **Card class** from **Bootstrap 4**, but there's an extra right space I can't get rid off:

[image]

(Ignore the 'porno' thing, heh).

As you can see, there's extra right space.

I'm trying to get rid of it with this code:

```
 .card{
     width: 80% !important;
     background-color: black;


 }


 .card-block{
    color: white !important;

 }

 #card-div{
     padding-bottom: 10px;
     padding-right: -10px !important;

 }

 #card-div > a{
     text-decoration: none;
 }
```

HTML code (using Jekyll too):

```
<div class="col-sm-8" id="main-content">

  <div class="row">

    {% for post in site.posts%}
    <div class="col-sm-4" id="card-div">
      <a target="_blank" href=" {{post.url}} ">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="../media/logo-prueba.jpg">
          <div class="card-block">
            <h5 class="card-title text-center">{{ post.title }}</h5>
            <p class="card-text">{{ post.category }}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}

  </div>

</div>
```

It doesn't works.

Any help?

Comment: Please share your html code.

Comment: Your question doesn't show any research effort. Also, negative `padding` values are illegal in HTML. You can use negative margins instead. However, that space is created by some CSS rule. It's better to disable the source than to apply additional code that reverts it. Do note that without a [mcve] (live snippet) in the question itself, your question is a lot less useful to future users, hence greatly reducing your chances of getting (good) answers.

Comment: share you html code

Comment: Share your html code

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu thanks for the observations. Will improve in future questions.

Comment: @karthik HTML code up!

Comment: @lalitbhakuni HTML code up!

Comment: @Pragya HTML code up!

Comment: i things it's working i'v don't see any problem https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FN09098T4E80

Comment: @lalitbhakuni well it might be some CSS I got. Will check.

Comment: I added more CSS rules I got in my project.

Comment: you giving `.card{
     width: 80% !important;` that's y  the right said getting space remove `80% important` https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FN0A1A0DDWZF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The width of the column element is determined by the col-type in CSS. This one has a width of 33.33%. The amount of pixels varies per breakpoint. Currently your column holds a card div. This card div is 80% of the column div. As it defaults to the left side, the remaining 20% appears on the right side. Adding `margin: 0 auto;` to the card CSS centers the div in its parent. Another solution would be to use a width of 100% (add `width: 100%` and remove `width: 80%!important`) on the card div, making it fill up the entire column.

Answer (score 1):

Adding bootstrap class "no gutters" helped me remove that:

```
div class="row no-gutters"
```